# connecting words with a integer field in a content type

Tags: views, nodes

I would like to have a content type with the following behavior.

A dropdown list with words that can be selected, when a user selects on or more words these words are added to the node. But every word should have an integer value connected to it, and these values should also be stored in the node.

The problem i'm having is i don't know how to connect the word with the integer value.

This is for a site where there is a periodic maintenance to equipment. The used spare parts in the maintenance would be the words, the integer is the price of the maintenance part. Afterwords i would create a view to add the total value of the integer so the technician can easily see how much the total value is of the used spare parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, really. Create a content type for parts. Use title for part name, remove body, add integer field for price.

In your "maintenance" content type, create [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to parts. That's all. Views are able to use Entity references ad views relationships, so sum of prices will be doable.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the fog. That makes perfect sense

Comment: Everything works except the view. I created a view that lists all the maintenance in a table.
I would like to show 1 table with the part and the next table with the price of that part.

I added the part and price field. then added the a relationship in to the parts field.

Then I can select in the price field to use this relationship but nothing shows.

Comment: @GoempieK Can you post a new question, then? Explaining what you have, showing view you created, and explaining (with diagrams / pictures, if needed) what changes you want?

Comment: Nevermind everything works. Stupid mistake i forgot to delete the rewrite output that i have been messing with.